Blazor Server side application oauth redirect
I am using a blazor server side application to get an access token to have that page call an API. it uses oauth for authorization code flow
so when /Ninja loads I have this code:
protected override async void OnInitialized()
 {
    if (DeviceService.Token != null)
     {
         
         var authorizationUrl = Service.GetAuthorizationUrl();
         Navigation.NavigateTo(authorizationUrl);
     }
     else {
          Console.WriteLine($"Token {Service.Token}"); //do stuff here in future with API calls
     }
}

the authorizationUrl is a URL from the oauth provider that returns a code for me to use as a query param
on my callback page (/Callback)
 [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "code")]
    public string? code { get; set; }

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The authorization code is required.");
            throw new ArgumentException("The authorization code is required.");
        }

        try
        {
            var accessToken = await _ninjaService.GetAccessTokenAsync(code);
            if (accessToken != null)
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/Ninja");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve access token: {ex.Message}"); 
//errors here all the time with :
    ///Failed to retrieve access token: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.
        }
    }
}

The access token is not null - so its present and valid but the router never changes so I am stuck on /Callback with the exception of  Failed to retrieve access token: Exception of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' was thrown.
Can someone help me? Ideally the app would route back to /Ninja and avoid a routing loop so with this new token I can call some APIs that require it

I reproduced your problem:

Solution:
You can put the NavigateTo method into OnAfterRender as shown in the following example:
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        try
        {
            var accessToken = await _ninjaService.GetAccessTokenAsync(code);
            if (accessToken != null)
            {
                Navigation.NavigateTo("/weather");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve access token: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}

After getting the token, I can navigate to the relevant page:



Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

OK this helped but part of my issue was I did not make the service _ninjaService a singleton so my getter was always failing after the Callback route
